# LWJGL Operation != undefined for type boolean, int

Tags: java, eclipse, lwjgl, glfw

I am following a tutorial on the basics of lwjgl. I am currently trying to make a simple window. However I am having two issues.

In my init() method I write

```
if(glfwInit() != GL_TRUE){
     throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to initialize GLFW");
}
```

and in my run() method I write

```
if(glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == GL_TRUE){
     running = false;
}
```

in both cases I get

```
Exception in thread "EndlessRunner" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
The operator != is undefined for the argument type(s) boolean, int

at Main.init(Main.java:28)
at Main.run(Main.java:43)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

However it seems that all tutorials use these lines in one way or another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java declartions of these methods are not quite the same as the C declarations so you need to adjust your code to match the Java declaration.

In both cases these methods return a `boolean`:

```
public static boolean glfwInit()

public static boolean glfwWindowShouldClose(long window)
```

so you use them using `true` and `false` rather than `GL_TRUE` and `GL_FALSE`:

```
if (glfwInit() != true) {

if (glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == true) {
```

Note: If Eclipse is showing there are errors in your code you will not be able to run it successfully.